# What algorithm is used by cvxopt.solvers.qp for quadratic programs in python

Tags: python, cvxopt, quadratic-programming

I am trying to understand what algorithm is used by cvxopt for solving quadratic problems.
I tried to look at the [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/cvxopt/latest/cvxopt.pdf) but I couldn't find any answer there too.

Answer (score 2):

> The function qp is an interface to coneqp for quadratic programs.

Let's start at the [official site](https://cvxopt.org/documentation/index.html#technical-documentation):

(remark: the user-guide and the technical-documentation are two different things)

> A discussion of the interior-point algorithms used in the conelp() and coneqp() solvers can be found in the report The CVXOPT linear and quadratic cone program solvers (pdf).

The [pdf](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/coneprog.pdf) contains:

> 5 Path-following algorithm for cone QPs

All those algorithms are [Interior point methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method). Some in self-dual form, some not (like your qp-solver).

The pdf should be enough to implement a basic version from scratch.